# Div with Text Shifting Other Elements Around

Tags: html, css

I have a set of images on my webpage. I attached a div before the image that will display some information about the photo. I shifted the div to fit my specifications, but the problem is that the image has also shifted to the right to fit the number of characters in my text. It should also be noted that there is PHP code involved in estimating the width and height of each image. To add or get rid of any tags or classes/ids would mess up the code. I'm at a lost at what to do now.

HTML Part

```
<div id="tube">
  <div class="part_1">
    <div class="text">wed  dfasdfasd  sda asd  sa asd </div>
        <img class="image_section_1"  src="https://encrypted-tbn3.google.com

        /images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRGr-DN5J2NpvVMVBcu-MgRFkN3S5CCpZ-H6OGxDLoNwNrYM9k3HQ" />

    <div class="text">wed  dfasdfasd  sda asd  sa asd </div>
        <img class="image_section_2"  src="https://encrypted-tbn3.google.com

        /images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRGr-DN5J2NpvVMVBcu-MgRFkN3S5CCpZ-H6OGxDLoNwNrYM9k3HQ" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
*{border:1px solid grey; padding: 0; margin: 0;}

html { background-color: whitesmoke; height: 100%; width:500%;}

#tube {  height: 100%; margin-top: 50px; padding-left: 10px;}

.part_1 {height: 44%; width: 100%;  }

#tube img {border-radius:5px; padding: 7px; background-color: white; padding-bottom: 

35px; border:1px solid grey; margin: 5px; box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px black;}

.image_section_1 {width: 5.4%; height: 67%;margin-right: 25px;}

.image_section_2 {width: 5.4%; height: 67%;margin-right: 25px;}

.text {display: inline; width: 100px; position: relative; left: 250px; bottom: 25px; 

overflow: hidden;  }*{border:1px solid grey; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

I also created a jfiddle example. As you can see, I want the images to be aligned next each other as well as having the left image only a few pixels off from the left border. http://jsfiddle.net/7xxxw/4/

Comment: and what's the desired result? how should it look like?

Comment: I want the image to only be a few pixels off from the left side. Also, I updated the jfiddle and as you can see the image on the right is a couple hundred pixels away from the left image. I know it has to do with the div that contains the text because the more characters added to the text, the bigger the spaces become.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

#### DEMO

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eRLqJ/)

#### HTML

```
<div id="tube">
    <div class="part_1">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRGr-DN5J2NpvVMVBcu-MgRFkN3S5CCpZ-H6OGxDLoNwNrYM9k3HQ">
            <p class="legend">wed  dfasdfasd  sda asd  sa asd</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
html { background-color: whitesmoke; height: 100%; width:500%;}

#tube {height: 100%; margin-top: 50px; padding-left: 10px;}

.part_1 {height: 44%; width: 100%;  }

.image {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 7px 7px 35px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px black;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.legend {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this out and it appears to not be working. Because a div was created around the image it screwed things up. Thankfully/Terribly, I have php code in here which dynamically plays with the images. I need an answer that does not add any div tags nor take any away. Thanks for the try though.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you should have mentioned that in your question.

Comment: Doing so I fear would have brought a rebuttal from people who thought the php code was unncessary. Nevertheless, sorry. I'll make sure from now on that I show all code. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Hey, not at all. It's very common to be forced to work with code you don't want/don't like in a project. If you're upfront about it people will understand.

Answer (score 0):

Put both the image and the text inside the same `<div>` and apply the location to that `<div>`. Add the text after the image.